# Cannot copy timeshift backup folder to usb flash drive

Tags: usb, permissions, backup

I want to copy a timeshift backup folder to my usb flash drive.

However anytime I try and move the file I get permission denied with this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2vxF.png

I have tried as sudo from terminal but same permission denied error, which is weird as I thought sudo let you do everything

Comment: please edit to add the terminal command you used. (something is weird in the directory name)

Comment: @cmak.fr thanks to your comment I seem to have fixed it. I looked again at the command and I hadnt included the -r as its a directory. thanks!